# How do I convert a Hexidecimal string to byte in C#?

Tags: c#, string, byte

How can I convert this string into a byte?

```
string a = "0x2B";
```

I tried this code, (byte)(a); but it said:

> Cannot convert type string to byte...

And when I tried this code, `Convert.ToByte(a);` and this `byte.Parse(a);`, it said:

> Input string was not in a correct format...

What is the proper code for this?

But when I am declaring it for example in an array, it is acceptable...

For example:

```
byte[] d = new byte[1] = {0x2a};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to specify the base to use in `Convert.ToByte` since your input string contains a hex number:

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(a, 16);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(a, 16);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk.aspx) function of the [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) helper class:

```
byte b = Convert.ToByte(a, 16);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

As others have mentioned, my original suggestion to use `byte.Parse()` with `NumberStyles.HexNumber` actually won't work with hex strings with "0x" prefix. The best solution is to use `Convert.ToByte(a, 16)` as suggested in other answers.

Original answer:

> Try using the following:
>
> ```
> byte b = byte.Parse(a, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
> ```

Comment: This would cause an exception if the string happen to be equal to `Pie` you should go into detail how to avoid this.  As `Douglas` explains this also would not work with `Ox` considering `x` is considering not to be valid in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UTF8Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question.

Comment: You may remove your answer then.