# converting byte to string and back again

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Byte from my database, stored as 0-254

i can convert it from a Byte to string using

```
byteVal.ToString() //0 return 0 20 returns 20
```

but to then return it back to a Byte I cannot figure out.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472906/converting-a-string-to-byte-array-without-using-an-encoding-byte-by-byte)

Comment: @DylanCorriveau no this question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert string to byte in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556805/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other number-types you need the appropriate `Parse`-method, in this case [`Byte.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Byte b = Byte.Parse("20");
```

If you don't know if the format is valid you can use [`Byte.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.tryparse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Byte b;
if(!Byte.TryParse("256", out b))
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid byte");
```

Comment: great thanks, that works, for some reason i thought it might give an ascii byte value back.
but i use Byte.TryParse(string); just in case it is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Convert.ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which converts string to a byte